# Maximum number of negation sign in a wff

Tags: logic

There is this question I am currently facing: Find the value of $f(n)$, which is the maximum number of negation sign one can have in a wff with $n$ atoms, without the subformula of the form $(¬(¬ \alpha))$, in terms of $n$.

This is my approach: consider $n=1$. Then I can have only 1 negation sign, by having $¬(A_1)$. Then by using recurrence, let $\omega$ be a wff with $n$ atoms and maximum number of negation sign, say $x_n$. Then for wff with $n+1$ atoms, I can take $¬(\omega ∧ ¬(A_{n+1}))$, so $x_{n+1}=x_n+2$. Solving it yields $f(n)=2n-1$. I did not consider $¬(¬(\omega) ∧ ¬(A_{n+1}))$ because $\omega$ will be starting with a ¬, so $¬(¬(\omega) ∧ ¬(A_{n+1}))$ will have the form of $(¬(¬ \alpha))$.

Is this correct?

Edit: $n$ is a natural number. And no limits of signs.

Comment: What is the meaning of $n$? Are you considering only propositional logic? Do you have $\bot$ and $\top$ in your language?

Comment: $n$ is a natural number. Yes, only propositional logic, and no limit of operators.

Comment: I see but what does it count? The number of atoms (i.e. propositional variables) in a formula?

Comment: Oh god. Let me edit the question again. Sorry.

Comment: Your solution is good.